# What accent can I put on "u" to make it sound like "you"?

Tags: pronunciation, diacritics

I have a made up name, "Bunar," and I want the *u* to sound like *you*, rather than *oo*. Is there an accent I can put above *u* to tell readers to pronounce it this way?

edit: feel free to explain how this is opinion based in any way. or why you bothered to close a month old question that's already been answered and accepted

Comment: English doesn't use accents with one exception. Ha ha. Beyounar.

Comment: If a name is spelled in English orthography, its pronunciation is arbitrary and cannot be determined from the spelling. That's the way English spelling works, and that's the reason for always asking for the spelling of the name of any English speaker. Or contrariwise, getting somebody to pronounce their name if you've only read it.

Comment: It's funny that the movie **Ferris Bueller's Day Off** is the right sound but it wouldn't work very well with Buenar. In any case, I would never use Bunar.

Comment: Bunar is a made up name, it is not an English word. English spelling is not phonetic, as such a person's invented name can be often pronounced several different ways until a final pronunciation is universally agreed upon. This is why I consider the question to be opinion-based and voted to close it as far back as July 3rd! You accepted an answer that  supported your *opinion* but see the comments underneath and consider that the best answer is Greybeard's

Comment: @Mari-LouA You mean we can’t just use the same accent mark that we use for each of the nine different vowels that follow /b/ at the beginning of each of *burr, butt, butte, bull, bulimia, bury, build, buy,* and *buoy*?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native English speaker, I would pronounce the name as you intended it to be pronounced (buːnə). With other languages, the pronuciation of vowel is denoted by accents over vowels, but English doesn't use accents and uses other ways to indicate vowel pronunciation. For example, if the intention that the vowel should be a much shorter sound, Bunar would be spelt with a double *n*, i.e Bunnar (bʌnə).

English also frequently places an *e* after a consonant to denote a longer vowel sound, e.g., take.

You're good to go.

Comment: Really? Bunar and lunar are not how the OP wants to pronounce it.

Comment: With a standard UK accent, I can see someone rhyming it with "tuner", though for me "lunar" would be /lu:/ not /lju:/.

Comment: buːnə doesn't have the "you" sound that the original post says in the name ... from what the question said, the pronunciation is supposed to be something like bjuːnə (starting with the same syllable as "beauty"). But, this is accepted, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you have is that readers pronounce a strange name the way they think it should be pronounced. No amount of accents will fix that.

Accents are pretty meaningless to the average English speaker and even when they are not, many choose the pronunciation of an accented letter that accords with a foreign language they are familiar with.

You might have some success with B**y**unar...

Comment: I wonder how do you spell it to make sure the R is pronounced correctly and never omitted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the unfamiliar (and arguably non-English) name Bunar to be pronounced /bju:/ then one way is to mimic the Welsh name *Beuno*. Spell your name **Beunar**; the /bju:/ first syllable actually makes the second syllable into a longer /nɑ:ʳ/ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider an umlaut over the ‘u,’ which is commonly used with German words like führer. No guarantee that your readers will interpret it appropriately but if you’re going to go the accent route (as opposed to a change in spelling or a decision to not care), I believe this would be the right choice.